# Why the object never move?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveToSettings : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float distanceToMove;

    private bool keepMoving = true;
    private Vector3 startPos;
    private Vector3 endPos;
    private bool moveBack = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        startPos = transform.position;
        endPos = transform.position - transform.right * distanceToMove;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (keepMoving == true && MouseDownEvent.mousedown == true)
        {
            if (transform.position == startPos)
            {
                moveBack = false;
            }

            Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, speed);

            keepMoving = false;
        }
    }
}
```

It should move to the right to the distanceToMove. distanceToMove in the Inspector is set to 30. But the transform never move.

Even if I'm removing the checking line :

```
if (keepMoving == true && MouseDownEvent.mousedown == true)
```

It won't move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never moves because you never assign to the transform's position. `Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, speed);` doesn't change anything by itself. You have to assign the result to something.  Also, you should use `Vector3.MoveTowards` and multiply `speed` by `Time.deltaTime` so that lag doesn't affect the speed:

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(startPos, endPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Also, you should use `Input.GetMouseButton(0)` to test for the mouse being clicked:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveToSettings : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float distanceToMove;

    private bool keepMoving = true;
    private Vector3 startPos;
    private Vector3 endPos;
    private bool moveBack = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        startPos = transform.position;
        endPos = transform.position - transform.right * distanceToMove;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {    
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(startPos, endPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`speed` is a constant value

[`Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) interpolates between two positions given a factor of `0` - `1`. This makes no sense like you are using it.

What you might rather want to use here is [`Vector3.MoveTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html)

```
Vector3.MoveTowards(startPos, endPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

---

Also see [`Input.GetMouseButton`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html)!

---

and note that you are calling the entire block only exactly **once** since you directly reset your `keepMoving` flag